# Algorithm for software keystone correction

Tags: java, image-processing

As part of my software I'm looking to write a keystone correction filter to avoid the tombstone / keystone effect you can get when projectors are displayed at an angle not perpendicular to the screen.

At present I've got something working, but it's incredibly slow (~100ms for the whole image) and ideally I'd want something a lot faster (preferably in the 10ms range.) I'm essentially just looping over the whole image pixel by pixel and copying the pixels I want into a new array, then setting the new image's rgb contents to this new array:

```
public BufferedImage getCorrectedImage() {
    double width = originalImage.getWidth(null) * 0.5;
    double increment = (originalImage.getWidth(null) - width)/originalImage.getHeight();

    BufferedImage ret = new BufferedImage(originalImage.getWidth(null), originalImage.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    for (int h = 0; h < originalImage.getHeight(); h++) {
        int[] arr = new int[originalImage.getWidth()];
        for (int w = 0; w < originalImage.getWidth(); w++) {
            arr[w] = originalImage.getRGB(w, h);
        }
        int[] newPixels = getShortLine(arr, (int) (width + 0.5));

        for (int w = 0; w < originalImage.getWidth(); w++) {
            ret.setRGB(w, h, newPixels[w]);
        }
        width += increment;
    }

    return ret;
}

private int[] getShortLine(int[] original, int newSize) {
    int[] newArr = new int[original.length];
    double scale = original.length / newSize;
    int start = (original.length - newSize) / 2;
    int end = original.length - ((original.length - newSize) / 2);
    for (int i = start; i < end-1; i++) {
        newArr[i] = original[(int) ((i - start) * scale)];
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

What would be the best way about doing this? A custom affine transform was initially what I was going to look at but I couldn't find any code / examples around to point me in the right direction. Is there a better way of achieving the result I want than the above?

Comment: Take a look at OpenCV. It is *really* fast, and has functions to correct virtually any lens distortion. Here's a promising Java wrapper for it: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Comment: @Blender thanks for that, I'll look into it. Only thing is if possible I'd like something in Java so I can keep things cross platform - there is JNA magic of course, but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: in that case, never mind. I'm not exactly sure how to help then, but you can look at the source code of OpenCV or another library if you want to see how they do it so quickly.

Comment: Just a quick question: what are the dimensions of your image? You might be hitting top speed, as that type of operation seems to be a bit slow by definition.

Comment: @Blender 800x600, so not huge at all - I was hoping to use this for 1080i video frames if possible (though looking at the speed it may not be!)

Comment: It's a bad idea to do this in Java anyway -- Java image processing is inefficient. It doesn't approach C++ levels of speed.

Comment: @Chris Dennett Point taken, but this is a comparatively minor part of the application and overall Java was (IMO) the best choice for it overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to speed up your existing code. A note of caution, these will make your code messier and harder to read... and debug. But if the algorithm is working, then refactoring for better performance might not be too difficult:

- Try using a [profiler](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers) to see if there's any less-than-obvious bottlenecks in your algorithm.
- You realocate a new array every time through the loop in your getCorrectedImage function. That is memory allocation that will add up over time. To speed things up create just one array (the largetst pixel width/heights) and reuse it throughout the lifetime of the function. You may need to add a few extra variables to track the actually used contents.
- Try inlining your getShortLine method. I'm not sure if the JVM will inline it at run time, or if there's a way to check whether it does. In any case, if the array reuse doesn't kick up your performance then it might be worth a shot to do the inline "manually."
- Just noticed that you could also make this function static. Just pass the originalImage member as a variable. This might also have a minor impact on performance, especially for class loading. It also makes sense to define it as static since the only variable seems to be the image and which can easily be passed in. I.e. no other class member dependencies. And it does seem like it should be a utility method in a utility class.

Check out [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/features.html) which is written entirely in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I'd actually tried both of the above already I just left it out of the above code for ease of reading. Both provided a small measurable increase, as did other things I played around with like getting the RGB contents of the image line by line as an array rather than with individual pixels. They speed it up a bit, but not the order of magnitude increase I'm looking for (ideally I want this working in real time processing things like video frames if possible.)

Comment: Have you tried a profiler to find bottlenecks? (Added that as an option into my answer.)

Comment: I have - unfortunately there were no obvious bottlenecks and the time spent processing was pretty evenly distributed throughout the algorithm. Definitely no single statement / loop taking 90% of the processing time or anything like that.